# Are there RTCs with 100 Hz output?

Tags: frequency, crystal, rtc

All RTCs I've seen so far operate from a 32.768 kHz crystal, which can't be divided to 100 Hz. Are there 32.000 kHz RTCs?

Comment: The ICM7170 is not obsolete anymore. Rochester Electronics is manufaturing old parts with original specs. The ICM7170 is one of them:
https://www.rocelec.com/part/REIICM7170AIBG-REEL?utm_source=SupplyFrame&utm_medium=SEP&utm_campaign=Jan_Mar23SupplyFrameSEP&utm_content=Jan_Mar_2023

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only RTC I know of which worked with hundredths of a second was the long obsolete Intersil [ICM7170](http://www.intersil.com/data/fn/fn3019.pdf). The datasheet isn't clear about how the 100 Hz was achieved. The crystal frequencies which it was designed for are perfect powers of 2: 32.768 kHz (i.e 2<sup>15</sup> Hz), 2<sup>20</sup> Hz, 2<sup>21</sup> Hz, and 2<sup>22</sup> Hz, yet the datasheet says it derives a 4000 Hz clock from them, from which the 100 Hz is derived. 32768 Hz is not a multiple of 4000 Hz, so this can't be done with a normal divider. They probably used a fractional divider, like *supercat* describes.

Anyway, the ICM7170 is obsolete, so we need something different. While there might not be 32 kHz RTCs, there are 32.000 kHz crystals, and with a [74HC4060](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4060.pdf) you get an oscillator + divider.

[image]

The 32 kHz crystal probably needs the same load capacitor as a 32.768 kHz crystal. The 330 kΩ resistor limits the drive power to the crystal. This is significantly higher than the 2.2 kΩ recommended by NXP; a 32 kHz crystal typically has a drive level of less than 1 μW. If the oscillator doesn't start decrease the resistor's value somewhat.
Use the :32 output Q5 (pin 5) to get a 1 kHz clock which you can feed to your microcontroller interrupt pin.

[image]

You can then use the 1 kHz heartbeat interrupt to derive a 10 ms software timer.

**edit**
Alternatively, a microcontroller can be used. This will be slightly more expensive than the 74HC4060, however, and might also consume a bit more power. I've used TI's [MSP430F1101](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f1101.pdf) at 32 kHz and 3.3 V which needed only 4 μA though. Run it off the 32 kHz crystal and use a timer to output the 100 Hz signal. You can even output different frequencies simultaneously, for instance 1000 Hz, 100 Hz and 1 Hz, or select the frequency on a specific output by setting a pair of I/O pins, or you can select the frequency via the UART.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want the 100 Hz for?  It's easy to turn a 32768 Hz signal into a 12800 Hz signal with +/-31 μs of jitter, using a circuit that outputs 25 pulses every 64.

With a little more work, one can reduce the jitter to +/-16 μs. With a bit more work still, one can reduce the jitter to +/-9 μs plus half the asymmetry of the input clock (so if the input clock is 12.5 μs high and 18 μs low, jitter would be +/- about 12 μs). I don't know of any current-production standard devices to do that, but it would be easy in a CPLD or FPGA. All but the last would fit in a 16V8; the last could probably be done combining a 16V8 and an external JK flip-flop.

Incidentally, one could, if desired, with a fairly similar amount of circuitry, generate 16000 Hz with the same amounts of jitter (output 125 pulses every 256).

Comment: If you don't use an RTC IC IMO there's no reason to stick with the 32.768kHz crystal. Granted, the 32.000kHz crystal may a bit more expensive, but not as expensive as a CPLD. And it doesn't show \$\mu\$s jitter.

Comment: @stevenvh: If one doesn't need a CPLD for anything else, a 32000Hz crystal and binary counter could easily be a better choice.  On the other hand, it's useful to know what options exist.  I was suggesting the 16V8 not so much with the idea that one would use a 16V8 just for that purpose, but because 16V8's are popular enough that I figured readers would know about how much logic that represents.  If any programmable logic is needed for some other purpose, the programmable logic device (of whatever form) may be able to do the rate conversion as well.

Answer (score 0):

I saw very good article by division of 1.25 or 2.5 to make 32768 Hz output from 10 MHz reference clock input. therefore in Arduino u can do the same. So, every 5 clock cycles count just 4. Timer 0 and 2 overflow occurs at frequency (16.000.000 / 256 / 64) = 976.5625 Hz.

If you divide this frequency several times by 1.25 you will get: 976.5625 / 1.25 = 781.25 Hz. Divide again by 1.25 and you will get 781.25 / 1.25 = 625 Hz. Divide that again by 1.25 and you will get 625 / 1.25 = 500 Hz. Nice round frequency. and 2 millisecond period.

Divide that again by 1.25 and you will get 500 / 1.25 = 400 Hz, power of 2 of 100 Hz frequency. Divide that again by 1.25 and you get 400 / 1.25 = 320 Hz, power of 2 of 10 Hz frequency, and finally divide that again by 1.25 and you get 320 / 1.25 = 256 Hz, power of 2 of 1 Hz frequency and it exactly fits to byte (2 to the 8th is 256). By dividing 1.25 you can have power of 2 of 1000 Hz, 100 Hz, 10 Hz and 1 Hz, so you can nicely handle miliseconds, centiseconds, deciseconds and seconds. 0

Comment: This looks like it could be a good answer, however, it is a bit difficult to read. Please [edit] and provide the link to the article. Also, some formatting (i.e. blank lines, spacing) would be helpful as your answer looks a little like a "wall of text".